# Codeigniter website not working after uploading to godaddy server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My website is working properly offline in wamp, but after uploading it to server, it stops working and giving error 404.

Also i unable to set home page offline in wamp.

My route.php and config.php and .htaccess are here

route.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'front_controllers/home/home_controller/index';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['index'] = "front_controllers/home/home_controller/index"; 
$route['tags'] = "front_controllers/tag_page/tag_page_controller/index"; 
$route['post/:num'] = "front_controllers/post/single/single_post_controller/index/$1"; 
$route['post/:num/:any'] = "front_controllers/post/single/single_post_controller/index/$1/$2";
```

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeIgniter/';
//$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

.htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

i already tried changing .htacess line

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
to
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Any way to set homepage in CI?
Any way to get it working on godaddy

Comment: any error you are facing?

Comment: Why would you think it cannot be run on Godaddy. What kind of hosting is it Linux/Apache/NGINX or Windows etc?

Comment: What version are you using? also post the files structure inside your `application/controllers` folder, @ravisachaniya why are you giving the link to the old user guide?

Comment: `$route['default_controller']` https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html?highlight=default_controller#defining-a-default-controller

Answer (score 0):

your base url is still `localhost` in config file `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeIgniter/';`. check this line and replace with domain url like this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/codeIgniter/';
```

but i recommend used base url like this

```
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$config['base_url'] .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Comment: I know but before uploading i changed it to http://sblogger.com but no luck